# Am I missing something for a random.sample based command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to have the bot take a raffle command from 1 to x and then pick y winning numbers

```
@bot.command(name='raffle',
         description="Command usage: !raffle x y",
         brief="Picks a number between 0 and the input x y times",
         pass_context=True)        
async def raffle(ctx, x, y):
    message = await bot.say(str('Generating random numbers...'))
    await sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message(message, new_content="Assessing the tallies...", embed=None)
    await sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message(message, new_content="Numbercrunching...", embed=None)
    await sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message(message, new_content="The number is.. *drum roll*", embed=None)
    await sleep(1)
    pool = list(range(1, (x)))
    z = random.sample(pool, k=(y))
    await bot.say(z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way discord saves arguments is as strings

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def example(ctx,x):
  print(type(x))
```

will print

```
<class 'str'>
```

And since all `range` parameters and the `k` parameter of `random.sample` take integers you have to convert `x` and `y` respectively to int

With that said, changing

```
pool = list(range(1, (x)))
z = random.sample(pool, k=(y))
await bot.say(z)
```

to

```
pool = list(range(1, int(x)))
z = random.sample(pool, k=int(y))
await bot.say(z)
```

and every `await sleep(1)` to `await asyncio.sleep(1)`

should do the trick